# Execute app install if test-path equals false

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script to test if a file exists in a target directory, and if false, execute an application installation.

The goal is to test if the file exists and if it does, abort with a log as to why. If the file does not exist, then the application installer should be executed.

I first tried creating a dummy file using New-Item to create both the directory and the dummy file.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "C:\temp"
New-Item -Path "C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "Updated"

# Test if computer is updated
$file = Get-Content "C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt"
$containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match "Updated"}
if ($containsWord -contains $false) { ###start running the install stuff
```

However, this errors out if the file does not exist with an Object-NotFound. I then decided to switch tactics and use `Test-Path`:

```
$file = Test-Path -Path "C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt"
if ($file -eq $false) { ###start running the install stuff
```

In this case, I believe `$file` would evaluate to False and as a result execute the installation. On execution all I get is a return of the script's path:

```
PS C:\users\me\desktop> $filetest = Test-Path -Path "C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt"
PS C:\users\me\desktop> $filetest
False
PS C:\users\me\desktop> C:\Users\me\Desktop\vistaupdate.ps1
```

The above reference to the PS1 file doesn't execute. It's only what's returned if I run the script through ISE as administrator. If I do the same with the console, then the output is blank without any action taken.

```
# Test if computer is updated
$file = Test-Path -Path "C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt"
if ($file -eq $False) {
    #package repository
    $VistaInsPath = "\\apps\shared\me\vista\6.16.0"

    #package installation command
    $VistaInsEXE  =  "VistaClient.6.16.0.896"

    #package installation parameters
    $VistaInsParam = "/s /v/qn"

    #logging
    $logFile = "\\apps\shared\me\vista\6.16.0\log\vista_install.log"

    #timestamp for logging
    function Get-TimeStamp {
        return "[{0:MM/dd/yy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
    }

    #main function
    function Vista-Install {
        $errFlag = $false
        try {
            $cmdLine = "$VistaInsPath$VistaInsEXE"
            Start-Process -FilePath $cmdLine -ArgumentList $VistaInsParam -Wait
        } catch {
            $(Get-TimeStamp) + "[" + $env:COMPUTERNAME +"]" + "[" + $env:USERNAME +"]" + "Error has occurred: " + $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logFile -Append
            $error.Clear()
            $errFlag = $true
        }

        #if no error, notify success
        if (-not $errFlag) {
            $(Get-TimeStamp) + "[" + $env:COMPUTERNAME +"]" + "[" + $env:USERNAME +"]" + "Completed Successfully" | Out-File $logFile -Append
        }
        # Place dummy file to tag computer as updated
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "C:\temp"
        New-Item -Path "C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "Updated"
    }
} else {
    $(Get-TimeStamp) + "[" + $env:COMPUTERNAME +"]" + "[" + $env:USERNAME +"]" + "Computer Already Updated. Aborting" | Out-File $logFile -Append
}
```

If `Test-Path` is False, then the installer should kick off in the first if statement. Instead the script spits back the path of the script itself and exits.

Comment: See `Get-Help Test-Path` or [read online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6) this returns a boolean you can check in an if or where-Object **not** a file location. BTW please read what a [mcve] is.

Comment: The code never calls the `Vista-Install` function. What are you expecting?

Comment: Have not read it all, but I can tell your `$cmdLine` construction is wrong. The way it is now, it wil return `"\\apps\shared\me\vista\6.16.0VistaClient.6.16.0.896"`. Use `Join-Path -Path $VistaInsPath -ChildPath $VistaInsEXE` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As [@lit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043596/execute-app-install-if-test-path-equals-false/54067268#comment94928335_54043596) already pointed out in the comments to your question, you never invoke the function `Vista-Install`, so it's rather unsurprising that your code doesn't actually do anything. And you shouldn't define functions (or your `$Vista*` and `$LogFile` variables) in a nested scope anyway. The code in the `else` branch won't be able to find `Get-TimeStamp` or `$LogFile` with what you currently have.

Allow me to suggest some improvements:

- Your logging code has a lot of redundant information. Instead of defining a function just for generating the timestamp, make a function that takes the log message as a parameter and otherwise completely encapsulates the logging.
- `$cmdLine = "$VistaInsPath$VistaInsEXE"` will combine directory path and filename without a path separator, resulting in an incorrect path. Either put a backslash between the variables:

  ```
  $cmdLine = "$VistaInsPath\$VistaInsEXE
  ```

  or (better) use the `Join-Path` cmdlet, as [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54043596/execute-app-install-if-test-path-equals-false/54067268#comment94938250_54043596) suggested:

  ```
  $cmdLine = Join-Path $VistaInsPath $VistaInsEXE
  ```
- Put `Test-Path` directly in the `if` condition. There's no need to assign the result to a variable first.
- The variable `$errFlag` is pointless. Just put the log statement after `Start-Process`. If an exception is thrown the code will go to the `catch` block without reaching that statement.
- I assume you want the file `vistaupdated.txt` created only if the installation didn't throw an error, so that code should go in the `try` block too.
- `New-Item` outputs an object for the item. You may want to suppress that.
- The function `Vista-Install` doesn't make much sense either, as it would only install one specific program. Since it has very little code to begin with I would just drop it and put the code directly in the "then" branch. But *if* you wanted it to be a function you should name and parametrize it properly: pass program and arguments as parameters (preferably named after the parameters of `Start-Process`, so you can simply [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) the [`$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#psboundparameters) variable) and use a name conforming to the [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands):

  ```
  function Install-Program {
      [CmdletBinding()]
      Param(
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
          [string]$FilePath,

          [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
          [string]$ArgumentList = @()
      )

      try {
          Start-Process @PSBoundParameters
          ...
      } catch {
          ...
      }
  }

  Install-Program -FilePath (Join-Path $VistaInsPath $VistaInsEXE) -ArgumentList $VistaInsParam
  ```

Simplified code:

```
$VistaInsPath  = '\\apps\shared\me\vista\6.16.0'
$VistaInsEXE   =  'VistaClient.6.16.0.896'
$VistaInsParam = '/s', '/v', '/qn'

$logFile = '\\apps\shared\me\vista\6.16.0\log\vista_install.log'

function Write-Log {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$Message = ''
    )

    "[{0:MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss}]`t[{1}\{2}]`t{3}" -f (Get-Date), $env:COMPUTERNAME, $env:USERNAME, $Message |
        Out-File $script:LogFile -Append
}

if (-not (Test-Path -Path 'C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt')) {
    $cmdLine = Join-Path $VistaInsPath $VistaInsEXE
    try {
        Start-Process -FilePath $cmdLine -ArgumentList $VistaInsParam -Wait
        New-Item -Path 'C:\temp' -Type Directory -Force | Out-Null
        New-Item -Path 'C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt' -Type File -Value 'Updated' | Out-Null
        Write-Log 'Completed successfully.'
    } catch {
        Write-Log ('Error has occurred: {0}' -f $_.Exception.Message)
    }
} else {
    Write-Log 'Computer already updated. Aborting.'
}
```

Arguments could be made for flipping "then" and "else" branch to avoid a negated condition:

```
if (Test-Path -Path 'C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt') {
    Write-Log 'Computer already updated. Aborting.'
} else {
    $cmdLine = ...
    ...
}
```

or exiting from the script directly if the file exists in order to avoid an `else` branch entirely:

```
if (Test-Path -Path 'C:\temp\vistaupdated.txt') {
    Write-Log 'Computer already updated. Aborting.'
    exit
}

$cmdLine = ...
...
```